# Create Variable or Method to use value in multiple forms

Tags: variables, ms-access, vba, global-variables

Fairly new to VBA. I have a list box on a form within Access which is populated with data from a table. Selecting a value from the list box gives and ID which is then used to perform a query. I need this ID to be available for use in another form to perform a query based on the Value. What is the best way of achieving this?

```
`Dim IDValue As String
IDValue = Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Companies.CompanyID = " & IDValue`
```

Comment: `Dim IDValue As String` Change it to `Public IDValue As String` and place it in a module.

Comment: You could simply add the ID to the query output and then continue to reference the query results.  Alternately (and I wouldn't really recommend this next way), you can create a public (global) variable by declaring it at the top of a standard module and not within any subroutines: `Public IDValue As String`.  Then you would assign a value to the public variable like you would normally, but it will be available for all forms to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a module

```
Dim IDValue AS Integer

Sub setIDValue(id As Integer) 
    IDValue = id
End Sub

Function getIDValue() As Integer
    getIDValue = IDValue
End Function
```

Then from any of your code

```
'This will set you ID
setIDValue YOUR_VALUE
'This will retrieve the value
getIDValue
'so your code could be 
setIDValue Me.Me.lstBoxCompanyName.Value
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Companies.CompanyID = " & getIDValue
```

Obviously this could use some Error Handling in the event that No IDValue is set. Also I used integer even though I see you are using a String the data type should be the same type as CompanyID so you can change Integer to String if needed but your will also have to change your query to `SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Companies.CompanyID = '" & getIDValue & "'` because your query implies a number currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to another forms controls by specifying the full path. Example :

```
Forms!MyFormsName!MyControlsName.Value
```

and

```
Forms!frmCustomer!CboCustomer.Column(0)
```

So if you want to access a value in VBA that is contained in another form and use it as part of a query it would look like:

```
CompDetailSQL = "SELECT * " & _
                "FROM Companies " & _
                "WHERE CompanyID = " & Forms!frmCustomer!lstBoxCompanyName.Value
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in ms Access you can also simply use form_NAMEofFORM.NAMEofCONTROL

Example you can reference

```
         dim myAmount as double
         myAmount = form_receipt.total
```

to access the value showing on form receipt textbox total.